# SceneKit: Zooming a camera in Swift 4

Tags: swift, camera, scenekit

In swift 2 you can use the `xFov` and `yFov` properties of the `cameraNode.camera!` to zoom the camera in and out. But they were deprecated in Swift 3.

I can adjust the z position of the camera using this code. . .

```
@objc func zoom(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    let view = self.view as! SCNView
    let node = view.scene!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Camera", recursively: false)
    let scale = gesture.scale

    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        break
    case .changed:
        node!.position.z = node!.position.z - Float(scale)
        break
    default: break
    }
}
```

. . .but changing the z position doesnt do anything. What do I use to accomplish this in Swift 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zooming turned out to be pretty easy, actually.

```
@objc func zoom(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    let view = self.view as! SCNView
    let node = view.scene!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Camera", recursively: false)
    let scale = gesture.velocity

    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        break
    case .changed:
        node!.camera!.fieldOfView = node!.camera!.fieldOfView - CGFloat(scale)
        print(node!.camera!.fieldOfView)
        break
    default: break
    }
}
```

Of course this does have its issues. It will continue to zoom in and out without any restrictions. But that can be easily fixed with some more code

**-EDIT-**

Bang! and with some quick `if-statements` I made some restrictions to the zooming.

```
@objc func zoom(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    let view = self.view as! SCNView
    let node = view.scene!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Camera", recursively: false)
    let scale = gesture.velocity

    let maximumFOV:CGFloat = 25 //This is what determines the farthest point you can zoom in to
    let minimumFOV:CGFloat = 90 //This is what determines the farthest point you can zoom out to

    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        break
    case .changed:
        node!.camera!.fieldOfView = node!.camera!.fieldOfView - CGFloat(scale)
        if node!.camera!.fieldOfView <= maximumFOV {
            node!.camera!.fieldOfView = maximumFOV
        }
        if node!.camera!.fieldOfView >= minimumFOV {
            node!.camera!.fieldOfView = minimumFOV
        }
        break
    default: break
    }
}
```

the lower `maximumFOV` is, the closer you can zoom in. The higher it is the less you can zoom in. The higher `minimumFOV` is the further you can zoom out. The lower it is, the less you can zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [ClosedRange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange) with a clamp extension to clamp the zoom between 2 values.

```
@objc func handleZoom(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
  switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:
      break
    case .changed:
      let scaleRange: ClosedRange = Double(2)...Double(14)
      let currentScale = cameraNode.camera?.orthographicScale
      let scale = recognizer.velocity
      let newScale = currentScale! - Double(scale)
      let clampedScale = scaleRange.clamp(newScale)
      cameraNode.camera?.orthographicScale = clampedScale
      break
    default: break
  }
}
```